# How do I copy and paste files from ubuntu as host OS to Windows XP as guest OS in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I just installed a virtual machine with Windows XP, but I am not able to copy and paste files from guest to host and vice versa, I set up clipboard setting on bidirectional but still i cant.

Comment: Have you tried to set-up `Shared Folder`?

Comment: Do you have GuestAdditions installed on the Guest OS?

Comment: @ Gen ...i tried shared folder i added host path of that folder to share in VM but not found on my guest OS

Comment: i got it in guestAddition ..thank you for help